# <data> element inside 404 response

Tags: java, web-services, rest, httpresponse

I'm trying to integrate with a RESTful web service and I've been told that 404 errors will now contain an error message wrapped inside a  XML tag.

Sample response:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Length: 170
Date: Tue, 15 Sep 2015 13:57:40 GMT

<data contentType="null" contentLength="170">
            <![CDATA[This is the error message.]]>
</data>
```

Does anyone know if this is standard practice? If so, how would I parse it? For successful responses we have an expected type defined in an XSD so we just use JAXB. Our client code is in Java. The admin of this web service says no XSD is required for this new 404.

I'm thinking either an XSD which describes this  element is required or this  element is something that's standard and there's an easy way to interpret it.

I've been given a snippet of code from the web service which is apparently used to generate the above response.

```
response.reset();
response.setStatus(errorCode);
   try {
      final PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
      writer.print(exception.getMessage());
      writer.close();
      response.flushBuffer();
   } catch (IOException e) {
      logger.error( e.getMessage(), e);
   }
```

Should I be asking for an XSD? Or is there some easy way to interpret this response? (besides just parsing out the message).

Any info would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

For the sample the admin gave he was pasting the HTTP headers from the raw response but then clicking the "XML" button in SoapUI which was adding the  stuff and then he pasted this underneath the HTTP headers. The  element isn't part of the response at all.